# Как объединить SQL запросы

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart, opencart2.0

очень прошу помочь, буду очень и очень благодарен.

Пытаюсь в Опенкарт 2 в модели объединить получение айдишников по атрибутам с получением данных товаров

пока у меня реализовано через циклы

```
//получаю список товаров имеющие определенное значение атрибута

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `os_product_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = '$att_id' and `text` = '$ImportAttValue'");
$product_ids = $query->rows; //тут имеем массив айдишников товаров

//получаю переменную $product_id = $product_ids['product_id'];
```

Потом я через foreach разбираю список товаров по $product_id

```
    $sql = "SELECT p.*, pd.* FROM `os_product` `p` LEFT JOIN `os_product_description` `pd` ON p.product_id = pd.product_id WHERE p.product_id = '$product_id'";

$query = $this->db->query($sql); //массив данных товаров
```

Как можно объединить эти 2 SQL запроса? Чтобы и получить айдишники ($product_id) и получить данные товаров сразу в одном массиве

Я себе представляю корявенько как-то так, но знаний не хватает без ошибок (плхо разбираюсь в синтаксисе sql):

```
SELECT p.*, pd.* FROM `os_product` `p` LEFT JOIN `os_product_description` `os_product_attribute` `pd` ON p.product_id = pd.product_id WHERE p.product_id = '$product_id' and `attribute_id` = '$att_id' and `text` = '$ImportAttValue'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навскидку так:

```
SELECT *
FROM os_product p 
/* LEFT */ JOIN os_product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id 
JOIN os_product_attribute pa ON p.product_id = pa.product_id
WHERE pa.attribute_id = '$att_id' 
  AND pa.text = '$ImportAttValue'
```

Comment: для теста проверил в таблице так
<pre>
SELECT * FROM os_product p 
LEFT JOIN os_product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id 
JOIN os_product_attribute pa ON WHERE p.product_id = pa.product_id
WHERE pa.attribute_id = '2' 
  AND pa.text = '22732'
</pre>

Ошибка

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE p.product_id = pa.product_id
WHERE pa.attribute_id = '2' 
  AND pa.text = ' at line 3

Comment: Да, опечатка. Удалите то WHERE, с которого начинается цитата в сообщении об ошибке.

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Все получилось!